# Can't access environment variable in django that set in the supervisor conf file

Tags: django, supervisord

```
[program:program_name]
command={gunicorn-path}
directory={path}
user={user}
autostart=true
autorestart=true
redirect_stderr=true
stderr_logfile=api_error.log
stdout_logfile=api_out.log
environment=ENV=my_env
```

I use the above supervisor.conf file to set the environment for my Django,
`ENVIRONMENT = os.environ.get('ENV')`
this way I try to access the env

Comment: have you reloaded reloaded/restarted the process? Are you setting just one variable called "ENV"?

Comment: yes, I did reload/restart the process, and yes, currently i have only one variable called ENV.

Comment: Do you get an error? How are you attempting to read the variable's value?

Comment: I don't get any error, os.environ.get('ENV') this way I tried to get variable,But its return None